# String.Intern() method missing in metro c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How to get string intern method in Metro c#. if not found in windows 8 c#, is there any equivalent method to maintain 
system's reference to the specified String.

Comment: You are using the most updated version of Windows 8?  It is my understanding that the Metro profile is significantly difference between each release preview.  If you cannot find it then you will have to implement your own solution.  You might be able to get away with simply using `ref` and a custom method perhaps an extension.  Describe what you are trying to solve, its very likely, you are going about it the wrong way.

Comment: I am interested in porting lucene.net to MetroLucene; They are using internpool for fieldnames.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an inevitable side-effect of the language projection built into the CLR that enables the ".NET for Metro style apps" api.  That projection maps a string that was obtained from a WinRT api call to System.String.  The underlying string is not a managed string at all and doesn't live on the garbage collected heap.  It is [an HSTRING.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br205775%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  The language projection makes it behave like a System.String

Accordingly, in that api, the String class doesn't have the methods that are very specific to managed strings.  Like Intern() and IsInterned(), that can only work for managed strings.  Copy, Clone and GetEnumerator are awol too.  There's no workaround for this, access to the managed String class in mscorlib is entirely blocked by the reference assemblies, it gets type forwarded to System.Runtime.dll.  You'll have to make it work without that method.

Comment: The reasons behind why we removed the methods on string isn't because of WinRT, but rather because we chose this opportunity to remove methods that either we regretted adding in the first place, or restricted our plans around innovating for the future.

Comment: String.GetEnumerator falls into the bucket of "we would not add it if we started again". In .NET Framework, it returns CharEnumerator, which is very inefficient for iterating over strings (it causes an allocation for each loop), and the code spit for foreach for both C# and VB haven't used this type since 1.0 days. (They now turn a foreach over a string into effectively a "for loop" that uses the string's indexer). While some of the removals might seem arbitrary, every removal was a deliberate choice and fell into one of the buckets above.

Comment: Case in point where someone detected the performance issue which I ran across as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259072/string-where-comparatively-poor-performance

Comment: That's a real bummer, because in F#, it being an Enumerable makes working with strings almost tolerable. :'(