# Why doesn't String class implement IEnumerable<char> in portable library?

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I've created a PCL project that targets .NET Framework 4 and Silverlight 5 (I use an extension for Visual Studio 2010, not portable project template from Visual Studio 2012, if that matters).
I am trying to reverse a string using `System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse<TSource>()` extension method, but it doesn't work because compiler thinks that `System.String` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<char>`, or is Intellisense just hiding it?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I get an error when I try to build it.

Comment: Hmm just checked the docs, and `GetEnumerator` is indeed not part of PCL. What was MS thinking...

Comment: Could you please post a link to the docs here? Thanks.

Comment: [String class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) scroll down to `GetEnumerator` and notice the missing PCL icon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Portable Class Libraries must restrict itself to the classes and methods that are available on all the target platforms it promises to support.  The biggest trouble-maker here is WinRT, the CLR has a language projection that maps WinRT types to managed types.  The System.String methods not supported by the projection are documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522718/17034).  GetEnumerator() is one of them.

Comment: That makes sense, by I didn't select WinRT (actually, it's called .NET for Metro style apps in framework selection window) as a target framework. I guess PCL should work as an intersection of selected platforms/frameworks.

Comment: Well, the point of PCL is that you *might* select WinRT some day.

Comment: Seems that we have slightly different visions here, but I am going to accept your answer for now, since I don't see any other point that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I don not understand why it should matter that you might select WinRT some day. I might select xbox some day, but that does not mean PCL is always limited to what xbox can do. Could you explain?

Comment: @Paul - Why don't you ask a question about it?