# Why doesn't the String class in WinRT implement IEnumerable<Char>

Tags: .net, windows-runtime

It seems like the string class in WinRT version of .NET does not implement IEnumerable. I wonder why on Earth did they do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate or related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557690/why-doesnt-string-class-implement-ienumerablechar-in-portable-library

Comment: Not a duplicate since the question is how to work around this. I am asking about the reason they did not implement it. Maybe string has some super native WinRT specific implementation or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "why?" is answered by [David Kean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218765/david-kean)'s comments beneath [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522718/55847):

> The reasons behind why we removed the methods on string isn't because
>   of WinRT, but rather because we chose this opportunity to remove
>   methods that either we regretted adding in the first place, or
>   restricted our plans around innovating for the future.
>
> String.GetEnumerator falls into the bucket of "we would not add it if
>   we started again". In .NET Framework, it returns CharEnumerator, which
>   is very inefficient for iterating over strings (it causes an
>   allocation for each loop), and the code spit for foreach for both C#
>   and VB haven't used this type since 1.0 days. (They now turn a foreach
>   over a string into effectively a "for loop" that uses the string's
>   indexer). While some of the removals might seem arbitrary, every
>   removal was a deliberate choice and fell into one of the buckets
>   above.

Comment: Great answer. However I cannot help but wonder why is the non-generic IEnumerable still implemented then. I mean what is the great difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerable<Char> if they are going to hardcode the implementation into the compiler anyway?

Comment: Also, how can you get away with `public sealed class String : IEnumerable` without `GetEnumerator()?`