# Any() does not compile in Portable Class Libraries; are there alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

How do I port the following statements to PCL?

```
using System.Linq;

string value = ...;

if (value.Any(ch => ch > Byte.MaxValue)) {
    throw new ArgumentException("String contains non-ASCII characters.", "value");
}
```

The code above does not compile and I always get the following error message:

```
Error   CS1061  'string' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no
extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Try `value.ToCharArray().Any(...)`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank u very much :-)

Comment: BTW—The test `ch > Byte.MaxValue` is inadequate to support the presumptive requirement of accepting only ASCII characters because the `char` values for ASCII characters are 0-127. So, the test incorrectly passes for the non-ASCII characters [U+0080 to U+00FF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [`string.GetEnumerator()` is not supported in the PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557690). so therefore the implicit implementation of `IEnumerable<char>` is not either.

You can easily get a character array that *should* support linq by doing

```
if (value.ToCharArray().Any(ch => ch > Byte.MaxValue)) {
    throw new ArgumentException("String contains non-ASCII characters.", "value");
}
```

I would note that there may be performance concerns creating an extraneous array if it's done a lot.  If you can measure a performance problem due to this, a lower-level method would be:

```
for(int i=0; i < value.Length; i++)
{
     char ch = value[i];
     if (ch > Byte.MaxValue))
     {
         throw new ArgumentException("String contains non-ASCII characters.", "value");
     }
}
```