# LINQ not working for strings in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have the following function:

```
    private static string SanitizeVersionStringFromUnit(string version)
    {
        var santizedString = new string(version.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray()); ;
        return santizedString;
    }
```

However, intellisense is telling me string does not contain a definition for Where and that no extension method can be found. I have `using System.Linq;` declared in the file. In a non-Xamarin project this code works fine.

This is a Xamarin.Forms PCL project in VS2015 Community. What gives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are getting the error because PCL version of `string` does not implement `IEnumerable<char>`. You can use `Cast` to make the code compile:

```
private static string SanitizeVersionStringFromUnit(string version)
{
    var santizedString = new string(version.Cast<char>().Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray());
    return santizedString;
}
```

See this question for more details: 
[Why doesn't String class implement IEnumerable in portable library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557690/why-doesnt-string-class-implement-ienumerablechar-in-portable-library)