# .NET Portable - Calling .Select() on a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, portable-class-library

I am trying to call the `.Select()` Linq extension method on a string from within a PCL, but I'm unable to compile the project. Calling `.Select()` on a string from a separate, non-portable project is compilable. I can see that `.Select()` takes in `this IEnumerable<TSource> source`. The string (and String) types implement `IEnumerable` inside of the .NETPortable assembly, so why should `.Select()` be unavailable? Can the compiler not implicitly convert strings to character arrays with PCLs for some reason?

Comment: Did you add `using System.Linq;` to your `using` directive?

Comment: Maybe not quite duplicate, but still relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557690/why-doesnt-string-class-implement-ienumerablechar-in-portable-library

Comment: IEnumerable and IEnumerable<char> are different interfaces.

Comment: @S.Akbari first thing I checked, I definitely have the using directive :)

Comment: @Peter has found the issue - the PCL string primitive type doesn't implement IEnumerable<char>, whereas outside of a PCL, it does. Add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler needs to implicitly convert a `string` to an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Whether this works depends on the platform(s) you are targeting with the portable library and thus what subset of the .NET Framework is available. If you target .NET Framework 4 and for instance Xamarin, you have a different subset than if you were targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1 and Xamarin. In the former case, the compiler will reject an implicit cast from `string` to `IEnumerable<char>`, while in the latter case it is accepted.

So the simple solution (if it is viable for you) would be to target .NET Framework 4.5.1 and higher. Otherwise, you may cast your string to a sequence of characters, e.g., using `.Cast<char>()`.

Comment: Or `string.ToCharArray` if it is available

Comment: The good thing about using Cast in this case is that on platforms where `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, the cast will not really do anything whereas `ToCharArray` will create a new array. On the other hand, yes, the cast itself may be expensive.