# String.Where Comparatively Poor Performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have two methods that take a string and remove any 'invalid' characters (characters contained in a hashset). One method uses Linq.Where, another uses a loop w/ char array.

The Linq method takes nearly twice as long (208756.9 ticks) as the loop (108688.2 ticks)

Linq:

```
    string Linq(string field)
    {
        var c = field.Where(p => !hashChar.Contains(p));
        return new string(c.ToArray());
    }
```

Loop:

```
    string CharArray(string field)
    {
        char[] c = new char[field.Length];
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < field.Length; i++)
            if (!hashChar.Contains(field[i]))
            {
                c[count] = field[i];
                count++;
            }

        if (count == 0)
            return field;

        char[] f = new char[count];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(c, 0, f, 0, count * sizeof(char));

        return new string(f);
    }
```

My expectation would be that LINQ would beat, or at least be comparable to, the loop method. The loop method isn't even optimized. I must be missing something here.

How does Linq.Where work under the hood, and why does it lose to my method?

Comment: How are you testing? Are you in release mode and outside of any debugger? Are you using a big enough sample size?

Comment: Well, first off, performance benchmarks for micro-optimizations are *really* hard.  There are a lot of common mistakes people make as to how they time their code, generally resulting in meaningless results.  You haven't shown the code you used to do the benchmarking, so I couldn't comment further.  Beyond that, this is clearly a micro-optimization that is highly unlikely to matter at all.  Find code snippets that are actually slow enough to be a likely bottleneck; spend your time optimizing *them*.

Comment: Just as a note, use `Stopwatch` for getting the times, if you are not already.

Comment: I'm guessing c in the first version is re-instantiated several times in your call.  In the second call, you avoid that, even with though you have two news.   Speed is probably more comparable with fewer 'hits', I'd think.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not really interested in optimizing a character removal method. It's entirely a curiosity. I'm running in release, using Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks. I build my strings and hashset outside the timer. Each method runs through 10,000 strings, 10 times. The results shown above are the average of the 10 runs. Obviously that isn't a large sample size, but the results have been consistent through ~15 executions.

Comment: Linq is not meant to be the most performant. It's meant to increase productivity with a reasonable tradeoff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [the source code of `ToArray` in Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs) is any indication, your implementation wins because it performs fewer allocations (scroll down to line 2874 to see the method).

Like many methods of LINQ, the `ToArray` method contains separate code paths for collections and for other enumerables:

```
TSource[] array;
var collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
if (collection != null) {
    ...
    return array;
}
```

In your case, this branch is not taken, so the code proceeds to this loop:

```
int pos = 0;
array = EmptyOf<TSource>.Instance;
foreach (var element in source) {
    if (pos == array.Length) {
        if (pos == 0)
            array = new TSource [4];
        else
            // If the number of returned character is significant,
            // this method will be called multiple times
            Array.Resize (ref array, pos * 2);
    }
    array[pos++] = element;
}

if (pos != array.Length)
    Array.Resize (ref array, pos);

return array;
```

As you can see, LINQ's version may allocate and re-allocate the array several times. Your implementation, on the other hand, does just two allocations - the upfront one of the max size, and the final one, where the data is copied. That's why your code is faster.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was looking for, the guts. I'd assumed it was in the Where() method though, not the ToArray().

Comment: @Michael `Were` may be partially responsible, too. You may benchmark this by constructing your strings in such a way that they always have exactly four characters to return, so as to avoid all reallocations inside `ToArray`, making its execution as streamlined as possible.