# PCL profile 111: String is not IEnumerable<char>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, win-universal-app

I'm working with PCL profile 111 and I can't use LINQ on a String. The following code

```
var text = "Just a string";
text.Last();
```

has an error "'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found."

It turns out that `String` in this PCL is not `IEnumerable<char>`. It is

```
public sealed class String : IEnumerable, IComparable, IComparable<String>, IEquatable<String>
```

My questions are:

- Why this PCL profile has a different implementation of String?
- What is the use case of this specific profile?
- Am I doing anything wrong?

More details on the project:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

[image]

Comment: David Kean explains the reason in the comments on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11522718/17034).