# Window with borders to be proportionally resized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, resize

I have a window with a tabControl in which there are 2 borders.
In the first border I have a listBox with some buttons.
Everything is fine but I have to add the capability to be resized by the user through maximize or manual drag.
So the first border has always to be some 33% of the window and so the second 66%.

So here is the window un-resized and it's correct
[image]

While when made larger you can see the two borders overlap and that's wrong and even the listBox that contains the buttons doesn't get resized.
[image]

here's my xaml

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/EasyRun2.0;component/Resources/Images/gradientWallpaper.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeMessage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="428,128,99.6,228"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20">
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="0,0,-0.4,0" Background="{x:Null}">
        <TabItem Header="&#xF0A7;"  Height="80" FontSize="50" Background="{x:Null}" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Margin="10,10,168.8,10.4" >
                    <ListBox x:Name="lbButtons" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="10,10,10,10" Loaded="lbButtons_Loaded"/>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="Border2" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="263,10,9.2,10" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="&#xF0F7;"  Height="80"  FontSize="50">
            <TabItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush/>
            </TabItem.Background>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="&#xF013;"  Height="80" FontSize="50" Background="{x:Null}" >
            <Button x:Name="ButtonAdd" Content="+" Tag="ADD" Background="{x:Null}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

thanks in advance
Patrick

Comment: Use HwndSource.AddHook() so you can intercept the [WM_SIZING message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11522718/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant is this a C# WPF method?

Comment: Have you tried using GridSplitter? afaik this is exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the grid `ColumnDefinitions` to be 33% and 66%.

Then put the two borders in each `Grid.Column` :
- `Grid.Colum="1"` or 0 by default

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--change-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
        <!--change-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="66*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Margin="10,10,10,10.4" >
        <ListBox x:Name="lbButtons" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="Border2" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,9.2,10" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks to the full code you posted, I could text it and it works

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use GridSplitter.
The code will look like:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border x:Name="Border1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Margin="10,10,10,10.4" >
            <ListBox x:Name="lbButtons" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
        </Border>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Columns" Margin="2"/>

        <Border x:Name="Border2" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="8,8,3,3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,10,9.2,10" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: GridSplitter doesn't answer the question but it is good practise to allow the user to manually resize the layout. I upvote :-)

Comment: Correct, looks like I misunderstand the sentence "I have to add the capability to be resized by the user through maximize or manual drag"
By manual drag I understand dragging the proportion.